# segmentation fault (dumped core)

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I tried to run the following program but I got an error message

> "Segmentation fault (dumped core)"

My code:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include "serialsource.h"

 int main()
 {

   FILE *pfile;
   char *filename="/home/menen/DataFiles/t2.txt";
   pfile=fopen(filename, "r");
   if (pfile == NULL)
    {
       printf("Can not open the file  /home/menen/DataFiles/t2.txt"); 
       exit(1);
    } 

    int i;
    char ch;
    char val[4];
    for(i=0 ;i<10;i++)
    {
      int count=0, j=3;
      ch=getc(pfile);
      while (ch != '\n')
      {
        count++;
        if (count>=62)
        {
          val[j]=ch;
          printf("%c ", val[j]);
          j--;
        }
        ch=getc(pfile); 
      }
      putchar('\n');

    }

    fclose(pfile);
    exit(0);

  }
```

Can anybody help me finding the issue in my code?

Comment: Run this in a *debugger*.

Answer (score 2):

In your case,

```
 val[j]=ch;
```

with unbound value decrement of `j`, it can go `-`ve, and access invalid memory which in turn invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

**General Suggestion:** Always check the validity of the index value you're going to use.

That said, [`getc()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getc) returns an `int` value. At times, the returned value may not fit into a `char`. Change

```
 char ch;
```

to

```
int ch = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        if (count>=62)
        {
          val[j]=ch;
          printf("%c ", val[j]);
          j--;
        }
```

Isn't there a high possibility that you might go `val[-1]` and below, looks like that's why you have segmentation fault.

```
if(j>=0)
{
  val[j] = ch;
  j--;
}
```

Make sure you don't have array out of bound access by having check like shown above.